Multi-class Classification with Categorical and Time-series Features
I have a problem where I want to classify certain entries into clusters, based on their categorical features (such as Country, Category, as dataframe columns), and also their selling pattern (time series, represented as columns month_1, month_2, and so on). In resume, DF format is ID, Country, Category, ..., sales_m1, sales_m2, ..., sales_m60. The clusters are done by considering only the sales info, that means, series shape is considered for that, by using KMeans prior to training.
I have tried Random Forest, with One-Hot Enconding, but since there are many categories by categorical columns, many features are generated (around 200).
When training the model, model accuracy usually is high. But when testing the trained model, on a data that I know their cluster in advance (I classified them with Kmeans to get their cluster, but removed then from training), it fails for 40% of the testing set.
I also tried CatBoost but no sucess either. Also Label Encoding... can you help me?
Is there a way to use both time series info and categorical values to a classification model?
